# What is the difference between "Geoinformatics and Geospatial Information Science" and "Geographic Information Systems"?

Tags: career

The following is information from the [Institute for Geoinformatics at Munster University](http://www.uni-muenster.de/Geoinformatics/en/Studies/study_programs/master/geoinformatics-in-muenster.html):

> - emphasis on Geoinformatics and geospatial information science instead    of focussing on geographic information systems.

Can anybody explain the difference between "Geoinformatics and Geospatial Information Science" on one side and "Geographic Information Systems" on the other?

Comment: "You say po-tay-toe, I say po-tah-toe..."  I'd be wary of institutions that want to make pointless distinctions for possible profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_science) reports that

> **Geographic information science** or Geographical information science
>   (GIScience) is the scientific discipline that studies data structures
>   and computational techniques to capture, represent, process, and
>   analyze geographic information. It can be contrasted with **geographic
>   information systems**, which are software tools

You can extent your readings with the [GIS page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) or the [Geomatics page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomatics)

Comment: Then Wikipedia says: *Geoinformatics* is the science and the technology which develops and uses information science infrastructure to address the problems of geography, cartography, geosciences and related branches of science and engineering.